# Add a .so library in a second project in Android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I build a source code in c++ in Android and I created a DSP.so. Now I want use this .so in a second project. How can i do? In my second project I have this estructure:

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)



include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := nativo.cpp Parameters.cpp 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl 
LOCAL_MODULE     := native_code


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

And my nativo.cpp

```
#include "nativo.h"

#include "Parameters.h"
#include <correlation.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace splab;

#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_TAG "NATIVO"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))


JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_vamostelo_Processing_init_1variables
  (JNIEnv *, jclass){

}



JNIEXPORT jchar JNICALL Java_com_example_vamostelo_Processing_prueba_1nativa
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong, jbyteArray, jint){


}
```

the file correlation.h is a file from the library wich i built. So how can i do to add this .so and that in my second project i can use the functions of this library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a "local shared library" from `DSP.so` and reference it when building your module.

An `Android.mk` such as this one should do it:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Create `DSP-prebuilt` local prebuilt library from `DSP.so`
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := DSP-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := path/to/DSP.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := path/to/DSP/headers/folder
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := nativo.cpp Parameters.cpp 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl 
LOCAL_MODULE     := native_code
# Reference the local prebuilt:
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := DSP-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Note that the resulting `libs` folder will contain both `libDSP-prebuilt.so` and `libnative_code.so`, which are both necessary as `native_module` only *references* `DSP`.

Hope this helps!